# Questions about conductivity

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance

The conductivity formula is as follows: conductivity = (length)/(resistance * area).

Let's say we want to measure the conductivity of a cubic material that consist two equal halves of different metals (so different resistance), what would the formula look like? Could we split the material into the two halves, measure the conductivity then add them?

Can we apply that same formula to a liquid?

Comment: Conductivity is a local property, either the current passes through material 1 or material 2. Conductance is the a property of the whole resistor, how to add two conductances together depends if the materials are connected in series or in parallel. That formula may not work on liquids.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How does a resitance affect electric current in a circuit...??(series)](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/671225/247642). See also: [Resistance and resistivity: which one is the intrinsic and which is the geometric property? Why?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/403100/247642), [Heating effect of electric current](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/680311/247642)